# Powershell Command to check for interactive account on a specific machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, account

Is there any command in PowerShell to check if an account is interactive or not on a specific machine?

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'interactive'?

Comment: @djones Here it is explained http://serverfault.com/questions/188115/what-is-windows-interactive-user

Comment: I'm still not clear.  Do you mean you want to get the INTERACTIVE identity or you want to determine which users have the right to logon interactively?

Comment: Still not clear; interactive is not a single property of an account which is switched on or off; accounts can have rights to interactive logon on some machines, but not others (or at some times, but not others).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I updated the question to check for interactive login on a single machine

Answer (score 1):

There is a Powershell module [Grant, Revoke, Query user rights (privileges) using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Revoke-Query-user-26e259b0) to work with user rights assignments.

```
Get-AccountsWithUserRight -Right SeInteractiveLogonRight
```